# 1500W wirewound resistor tripping house fuse 20A / 120V

Tags: ac, power-electronics

I have a TE wirewound resistor (TE Connectivity TE1500B22RJ,  TE series solder lug panel mount resistor, 22 ohms +/-5% 1500W), which I am hooking up a 120V outlet rated up to 20A.

[image]

I am testing a mechanical switch which is rated up to 20A. I have the switch wired up to this resistor to act as a load.

I thought with this resistor, I would be pulling under 20A, but I am not certain because I keep blowing the fuse on my AC mains fuse breaker.

If you hooked up this resistor to AC mains, at 120V, with 22ohms of resistance as per the data, doesn't that imply ~650 watts / 5.4 amps?

I orignally thought the current being drawn would be I = P/V, or I = 1500 watts / 120V = 12.5 amps.

If my breaker is rated to 20 amps, does anyone have any ideas why this would be tripped when I plug it in?

Is there something obvious I am missing here in the datasheet or on-rush current on the breaker perhaps?

---

Setup without switch:

(Yes ignore the suicide cords everywhere; the resistor is sitting on a ~1/2" thick pad of plastic as an insulator.)

[image]

Comment: Just as a sanity-check, could you draw us a diagram and/or show us a pic of exactly how you've got this wired up?

Comment: What else is on that circuit?

Comment: @vir -- that's a good observation, there may be a few amps sitting on that circuit.

Comment: When the resistor gets hot it is likely to melt the plastic. Housebricks, as an example, will be able to withstand the temperature. It won't *look* hot, so something like silicone oven gloves may save your hands from very painful burns that take weeks to heal. Make sure it is secure so that it can't fall or move anywhere.

Answer (score 9):

You have connected the line and neutral wires to the threaded rod that holds the mounting bracket on, essentially shorting them.  The real terminals are the ones sticking straight up.  Also, please have a box fan or something blowing on it so you don't burn your house down.  Those resistors are rated for 100% nameplate in free air but even at 50% you're still looking at almost 300C temperature rise.

Comment: There we go.  That seems a bit safer. ;) -- Any idea what you you can thread for the wires?

Comment: I used #10 or 1/4" screws and nuts to hold appropriately sized ring terminals on.  It's going to smell gross for a bit the first time you turn it on, which is normal.  Do it in a ventilated area if you can, and make sure there are no little styrofoam crumbs from the packing on it.  Also consider getting an inline GFCI from the hardware store.

Comment: I went to Home Depot prior to your comment and sourced out a machine bolt + screw just by eyeballing.  Indeed, that thing reeks when it gets powered up.   Part of what I am trying to measure is the current the switch materially can handle, and indeed it is not 15A as rated, but is more like 1A....  So this science experiment, did yield something useful besides burning down my office.   Thanks for the direction on the tabs -- the datasheet doesn't indicate anything!

Comment: @Leroy105 It's a good idea to always measure the resistance between the terminals you are about to connect to on high power devices. A 22 Ohm resistor won't read as a dead short...

Answer (score 8):

1. Disconnect the resistor and measure the value to verify it is what you ordered. Mistakes happen. Short your multimeter leads first to determine the '0' value and subtract that from the subsequent value if it's significant (usually it will be less than an ohm, so not significant in this context).
2. Your breaker may be old and tired if it has tripped many times. They sometimes trip early when they are like that. Or maybe the breaker is rated for less current than the outlet. Check the breaker markings.

---

Edit:

You appear to  have connected to the wrong part of the resistor. You should have connected to the tabs that are sticking up. A resistance measurement will confirm that. Thanks to @brhans for suggesting the photo.

Comment: If this is a 1500 watt / 22 ohm resistor, in an 120V AC circuit, is ~5.5 amps?

Comment: The resistor power rating does not matter (so long as it is higher than the actual dissipation). The RMS current should indeed be 120VAC/22 ohms = 5.45A. And the power dissipation about 655W.

Comment: Thanks!  I get it.  That makes sense.

Comment: Well if I didn't have an old and tired fuse in that circuit before, after whacking on it twice with a dead short.... I may now. ;)